# How me be Sneaky Goblin Bomber?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, roleplaying

I was playing the Pathfinder module ***We be Goblins!***

During Part 1, our group was trying to sneak into a house. As I started to use my bomb, other goblins start to bully me.

At the end of the session I can't stop asking my self: how could a mad goblin bomber could have been stealthier?

As it's a pre build character I can't modify it.  I am looking for information about goblin bomb making with no noise (in this storyline), or roleplaying advice.

> As a neutral evil character, it looks difficult to not use a bomb when you face the dog 'Calin'(French name for hugs), that sleeps in the room above the boss room.

Comment: Well the question is close now! But yeah the question was about pathfinder rules or rules in this senario that i was not aware of. Because setting a bomber on senario than can imply stealth was really hard for me Almost killed my party in a My guy moment. I will edit it with offical material to make it clearer. Fro those who know a bit about the 2nd part of we be gobs.. There must be Something saying that i can use bomb without alerting all the house.

Comment: Rephrase it more specific and you might be helped.